# Image Thumbnails from Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I was wondering if the Google Drive API is going to generate multiple Thumbnail images for uploaded Photos to Google Drive in the near future. I am a developer of Cloud Photos (iOS App), and our integration with Dropbox and Facebook (coming soon) is powered by these thumbnail images generated for each photo uploaded to their service. I know we are very interested in integrating Google Drive, and generating thumbnails for uploaded Images would allow many developers with photo based apps to integrate with Google Drive.

Answer (score 4):

This is not currently supported but something we could add in the future with a Picasa/Drive integration. There are no finite plans to implement this at the moment though.

Thanks for the feature request and for the feedback!

Comment: Any update on this?. Since it has been over a year may be things have changed?